# How to iterate over words in each row using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["Hi how are you","I am fine","I love you","I hate you"],
                   'tokens':[('Hi','how','are','you'),('I','am','fine'),('I','love','you'),('I','hate','you')]})
```

I would like to get the pos tag of each token

```
for tok in df['tokens'].iterrows():
  print(token, token.pos_)
```

Please note that the `pos_` here mean it is part of speech tag from nlp domain

However, I get an error

Can help me on how can I iterate over each item in the pandas column?

Comment: what is  your the expected output from the given dataframe?

Comment: Not sure if you want this or not but you can try `df['pos tag']=df['tokens'].map(lambda x:range(len(x)))`

Comment: @TheGreat Check `df['tokens'].map(lambda l: [t[1] for t in nltk.pos_tag(l)])` or `df['tokens'].map(nltk.pos_tag)` if you need pairs.

Comment: I'm not sure about spacy but `df['text'].map(lambda s: [t.pos_ for t in nlp(s)])` could work.

Comment: Is this correct `text_df['tokens_without_sw'] = text_df['tokens'].map(lambda s:[w for w in s if w not in all_stopwords])`

Comment: @TheGreat That's correct.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - Sorry, again, I am encountering a trouble on this map and lamba. I would like to iterate over indvidual tokens..`df['tokens_without_sw'].map(lambda s: [w.label_ for w in nlp(s).ents])`... Here, instead of indvidual token as input for `w`, it is giving me that full row. How do I get only that specific token (from that row)?

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got list)`. But similar command earlier (shared above) for another column worked fine..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234478/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-the-great).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'` because you are using the column `df['tokens']`, which gives a series (1 dimension only), so there's no iterrows method.

Using your code you could do:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["Hi how are you","I am fine","I love you","I hate you"],
                       'tokens':[('Hi','how','are','you'),('I','am','fine'),('I','love','you'),('I','hate','you')]})
    
    for index, values in df.iterrows():
        pos = 1
        for x in values[1]:
            print(pos, x)
            pos += 1
```

Alternatively you could use (similarly to what @AnuragDabas commented):

```py
df['pos tag'] = df['tokens'].apply(lambda x:list(range(len(x)+1))[1:])
```

All you need is `df.iat[2,1][1]` ;)